# Interesting CTA Immigration Question

Tags: transit, ireland

I do wonder, due to the peculiarities of the Common Travel Area between Ireland and the UK, if the following hypothetical scenario is possible:

- A non-EU citizen flies Boston-Dublin-London with airside transit in Dublin. Will this non-EU citizen undergo an immigration check for the UK at any point? As airside transits, by nature, do not have immigration checks and the final flight (Dublin-London) does not have an immigration check upon arriving into the UK.

This scenario is completely hypothetical, but I just wonder if this happens in real life or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Of course they've thought of that, which is why flights within the CTA don't depart from the international transit zones at LHR, LGW, and MAN; you have to go through immigration to get from an international flight to a CTA flight.

Note also that DUB doesn't have an international airside transit zone; all DUB arrivals from outside the CTA go through immigration. (Edit: It's unclear to me whether arrivals from the UK may still go through immigration in Dublin.)

Comment: Even passengers arriving from the UK go through immigration in DUB.

Comment: Shannon as well